# chart.js - display control timescale time zone

Tags: timezone, momentjs, chart.js

I want to configure one chart to have a different timezone (for example I'm in utc+00 and want to display data in utc+01)

Is there a way? according to docs I have to return a moment object, and then date displays according to moment global locale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the time configuration options specify `parser` as a function:

```
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            unit: 'hour',
                            min: minDate,
                            max: maxDate,
                            displayFormats: {
                                hour: 'HH'
                            },
                            parser: function (utcMoment) {
                                return utcMoment.utcOffset('+0100');
                            }                
                        }
                    }]
```

As well as converting the chart values this will also apply to the min/max values of the x axis.

This assumes your min/max values and label array is populated with moment objects. If dealing with date objects then the function needs to convert the date to a moment first.

```
parser: function(date) {
    return moment(date).utcOffset('+0100');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! For some reason, though, in my environment the function `utcOffset()` did not exist on the `utcMoment` parameter. My workaround was to do `return moment(utcMoment).utcOffset('+0100');`

Comment: @RobinZimmermann Your label array and/or min//max values are probably date  objects rather than moments to begin with. A bit of an assumption on my part.

Comment: Ah, of course, you're right! The dataset came from a MongoDB query in Meteor, so they were date objects.

Comment: This is not a robust solution. I tried to combine it with chartjs-plugin-zoom and the behaviour is very bad, it seems it's running something with the axes values through this function whenever it performs a zoom or pan operation.

Comment: @BarrySmith have you maybe got a solution for this problem? The parser definitely still breaks my zoom, nevermind the labels that do not get changed to the required timezone

Comment: @Loupi Couldn't fit it well into a comment so I made an answer.

Comment: `Chart.bundle.js:10169 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined`

Answer (score 2):

I use a callback on the ticks function. That way you only change the label.

```
import Moment from 'moment';

//...

const options = {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        ticks: {
          callback: (label, index, ticks) => {
            const format = 'DD HH'; // Change how you please
            return new Moment(ticks[index].value)
              .utcOffset(this.timeZoneOffsetSeconds / 60)
              .format(format);
          }
        }
      }]
    },
    // other options removed for clarity
  };
  
this.chart = new Chart(chartElem, {
  options: options,
  // other parameters removed for clarity
});
```

Note on the example: Moment is deprecated, apparently there are better libraries out there but that's what I have in my codebase so...

Comment: Wow, actually did not expect a reply this fast. Really appreciate it! I also started using the tick callback now. Tried the chartjs-adapter-luxon but could not get that working either. Probably going to have to go with moment for now even though it is legacy.